# Can't see business rules within form designer of Dynamics 365 - "Can't connect to your business rules Reloading the pane usually fixes this problem."

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I can access business rules through the standard Column > Business Rules menu but when trying to access them within the D365 form designer, I'm unable to see any at all. Refreshing does not fix the problem. The problem exists between multiple devs and browsers.

[image: Screenshot of Business Rules sidebar showing the error "Can't connect to your business rules, Reloading the pane usually fixes the problem"]

Comment: yeah, we all are facing the same issue, across all environments :( I don't think that there's anything you can do at the moment, aside from wait for microsoft to address the issue.

Comment: Quick Update: The issue was resolved for our tenant today :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft support, they have confirmed that this was a bug. As of 17/02/2024 they have confirmed that it is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has happened to me.

It works in Classic UI and Business rules on a form on the table in the solution.

I have been communicating with Infosys; they are aware of it and on high priority. They said it will take 1-2weeks to get fixed.

from Jay